# How much realistic should be a model in domain driven design?

Tags: domain-driven-design, software-design

In Eric Evans book on domain driven design it is written:

> Domain modeling is not a matter of making as “realistic” a model as
>   possible. Even in a domain of tangible real-world things, our model is
>   an artificial creation. Nor is it just the construction of a software
>   mechanism that gives the necessary results.

Now I have two questions:

1. Should a model be designed 
   somehow that it could evolve to a more
   realistic shape whenever NEEDED
   without touching the core model in previous iteration?
2. If the answer to the previous question is positive, where can I learn how to create realistic core models?
3. Again if the answer to the question one is possible, would a day come that our model reflects any problem in the world?

Comment: You should think about what the word model means. A model is a simplification of reality. If you want a model as complex as the reality, probably you are doing it wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Domain Model` should `not reflect real world`.
It should only show one point of view depending on the context.

Let's say we got a `glass`.

- One may think, well it's a glass and we can fill it with water. It is used `to drink`.
- Other may think, well it's a product and we can `sell it`.
- Another one may say, glass an inventory item. I don't care how does it looks like, but `how many` glasses I got here.

Depending on the context, we `model glass differently`. Still it is the same glass, but means something else.

All information related to the subject you can find on Udi Dahan's blog.
And more in the subject of modeling reallity, can be found here   [Don’t try to model the real world, it doesn’t exist.](http://udidahan.com/2012/03/05/dont-try-to-model-the-real-world-it-doesnt-exist/)

Comment: Thank you very much. This is the best answer so far. Now I have a better view. Let me give you an example. I was asked to create an e-shop and I started by having a table of concepts in which one row is apple the another table named conceptInstances point at concepts and then another table called providingInstances pointing ar concept instances. When the user wants to add some apple to provide the buyer with, he says I wanna sell some apple and the app asks hime how much apple he has (since apple concept has weight) etc. Is this aproach wrong ?

Comment: It doesn't give me much insight. I guess you're thinking about data instead of behaviour. 
In DDD, you do not start with database tables, because it will make your domain model [anemic](http://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html)
Focus on the behaviour of the objects, `leave the data` behind you till you know how the `model interact`. And, if you need to have database at start, you should get back to the blue book, it doesn't work that way.
I recommend you `Red Book` by Vaughn Vernon, it's much simpler to start with it than with `Blue Book`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I read the anemic anti pattern. I am not yet persuaded why we should not have class called Glass with a property called volume. Aren't the glasses from any point of view, the objects to hold a certain volume of liquid inside? Then I add different contexts by using decorator pattern. Why is that bad?

Comment: "Aren't the glasses from any point of view, the objects to hold a certain volume of liquid inside?"
No. Look from seller perspective, he doesn't care, if you hold liquid inside, or you put it as decoration on your table. All he does care about is prize, nothing more. 
And different context, is different subdomain. In one context you have model with specific boundaries, you don't decorate your models using decorator pattern to move out of the boundaries. 
Read this to get more overview: http://gorodinski.com/blog/2013/04/29/sub-domains-and-bounded-contexts-in-domain-driven-design-ddd/

Answer (score 2):

> 1. Should a model be designed somehow that it could evolve to a more realistic shape whenever NEEDED without touching the core model in
>      previous iteration?

No, a model should reflect the particular problem under consideration.  If the underlying problem changes, the model should reflect it.  Let's say your modeling a hotel reservation system, a warehouse system, or a store point-of-sale system, your model should be a representation of the *current* concepts in those domains and the interaction between them.  Models are not versioned over time.

> 2 and 3

No.

Comment: Do you have any proof for 3?

Comment: @MohammadRahmani Your abstractions should stay as close as possible to your domain, without trying to solve all potential upcoming problems. Wide abstractions would give more flexibility to your domain, but will also drag your code away from the domain. You should always strive to get the right balance. Still, if your abstractions are named after domain concepts then there may be less harm.

Comment: @plalx thank you. Let me give you an example. I was asked to create an e-shop and I started by having a table of concepts in which one row is apple the another table named conceptInstances point at concepts and then another table called providingInstances pointing ar concept instances. When the user wants to add some apple to provide the buyer with, he says I wanna sell some apple and the app asks hime how much apple he has (since apple concept has weight) etc. Is this aproach wrong ?

Comment: @MohammadRahmani how does this relate to your original question ? We can't tell you if it's a wrong approach without knowing more about your domain.

Comment: Aryeh @guillaume31 please follow my converstion with daris in the comments of the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

In a problem domain, there are obvious things and hidden things.

If you just model the obvious, apparent notions (whether real world objects or intangible concepts), creating a class for each one, you will have a *realistic* model but it will miss the point. It won't be a deep, insightful domain model.

To go beyond mere realism, you should sit with a domain expert and try to discover the hidden things in the problem space that will be helpful to the solution space - your application.

For instance, talking to a railway traffic expert, you might uncover heuristics or properties in the way train departures and arrivals are orchestrated that even the expert didn't realize or put a name on before. Naming these things will allow you to reason about them and ultimately act on them in your application. Or, you might have an elephant in the room - a big, widely used historical concept - and decide to reject it from your ubiquitous language because it doesn't describe a subpart of the problem accurately enough.

*Realistic* here is meant as opposed to *refined, rationalized*, not to *totally made-up*.